# How was Git designed?

Tags: design, version-control, git, linux

My workplace recently switched to Git and I've been loving (and hating!) it. I really do love it, and it is extremely powerful. The only part I hate is that sometimes it's too powerful (and maybe a bit terse/confusing).

My question is... **How was Git designed?** Just using it for a short amount of time, you get the feel that it can handle many obscure workflows that other version control systems could not. But it also feels elegant underneath. And fast!

This is no doubt in part to Linus's talent. But I'm wondering, was the overall design of git based off of something? I've read about BitKeeper but the accounts are scant on technical details. The compression, the graphs, getting rid of revision numbers, emphasizing branching, stashing, remotes... Where did it all come from?

Linus really knocked this one out of the park and on pretty much the first try! It's quite good to use once you're past the learning curve.

Comment: probably you could get some help on the git IRC channel (#git on freenode)

Comment: Check out [Tech Talk: Linus Torvalds on git](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8)

Comment: `you get the feel that it can handle many obscure workflows that other version control systems could not`: That's probably because it was designed to handle the linux kernel, a notoriously hackish, large and complex piece of code.

Comment: On the 10th anniversary of Git, here's an article from an interview with Torvalds: http://www.linux.com/news/featured-blogs/185-jennifer-cloer/821541-10-years-of-git-an-interview-with-git-creator-linus-torvalds

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Git was not designed as much as *evolved*.

Take a look by yourself. Clone the [official git repository](https://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=summary), open it in `gitk` (or your favorite graphical git log viewer), and look at its earliest revisions.

You will see it originally had only the very core functionality (the object database and the index). Everything else was done *by hand*. However, this small core was designed to be easily automated via shell scripting. The early users of git wrote their own shell scripts to automate common tasks; little by little, these scripts were incorporated into the git distribution (see for an early example [839a7a0](https://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commitdiff;h=839a7a06f35bf8cd563a41d6db97f453ab108129)). Every time there was a new need, the scripts were adapted to allow for it. Much later, several of these scripts would be rewritten in C.

This combination of a clean, orthogonal core (which you can still use directly if you have the need), with an upper layer which grew organically over it, is what gives git its power. Of course, it is also what gives it the large amount of oddly-named commands and options.

---

> The compression, the graphs, getting rid of revision numbers, emphasizing branching, stashing, remotes... Where did it all come from?

A lot of that was not there in the beginning.

While each object was individually compressed, and duplicates were avoided by their naming, the "pack" files which are responsible for the high compression we are used to seeing in git did not exist. The philosophy in the beginning was "disk space is cheap".

If by "the graphs" you mean graphical viewers like `gitk`, they appeared later (AFAIK, the first one was `gitk`). AFAIK, BitKeeper also had a graphical history viewer.

Getting rid of the version numbers, in fact git's core concept of using a content-addressed filesystem to store the objects, mostly came from [monotone](http://www.monotone.ca/). At that time, monotone was slow; if this were not the case, it is possible Linus would have used it instead of creating git.

Emphasizing branching is somewhat unavoidable on a distributed version control system, since each clone acts as a separate branch.

Stashing (`git stash`) is, IIRC, quite recent. The reflogs, which it uses, were not there in the beginning.

Even remotes were not there initially. Originally, you copied the objects by hand using `rsync`.

One by one, each of these features was added by someone. Not all of them — perhaps not even most of them — were written by Linus. Every time anyone feels a need which git does not fulfill, one can create a new feature over git's core "plumbing" layer, and propose it for inclusion. If it is good, it probably will be accepted, enhancing git's utility (and its command line complexity) even further.

Comment: "AFAIK, BitKeeper also had a graphical history viewer." Yes, it does. It's not exactly pretty, but it's highly functional. See http://www.bitkeeper.com/Test.Using.Looking.html, though that does a poor job of showing how it displays branches.

Comment: Also an interesting read, a few select emails from the beginning of git, showing a bit of its initial evolution: http://kerneltrap.org/node/4982

Comment: Did programmers used to emulate some functionality of git with cvs + rsync + httpd? I'd be interested to hear what homemade solutions were possible.

Answer (score 8):

I think the main point is simply that git was designed by the single most qualified person on the planet to do so. And I am not talking about talent, I am talking about experience: I doubt there is anyone else who's been in charge of a codebase with a comparable combination of size and number of contributors as the Linux kernel and still actually dealing with most of the integration work himself.

So Linus knew the requirements and use cases for a distributed version control system better than anyone else. And of course it helped that most of that coding he was dealing was in C, and much of it performance critical.

Basically it's the ultimate example of scratching one's own itch.

Comment: "Single most qualified"? I don't think so. There are many smart people who are qualified to write distributed source control. The guys at BitMover (the company behind BitKeeper) really _really_ know what they are doing. Linus even gives credit to Larry McVoy for showing him how source code control _should_ work. Without Larry there would be no git.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I think we can avoid bashing when someone's complementing someone for something good. High-inside everyone knows that requirement makes a great developer. So, If tomorrow, you are presented with a great problem, we might remember you, as we do Dennis Ritchie. No one's better than the other, it just that they came across a requirement worldwide acknowledged and provided a solution first.

Comment: @Bryan: I'm sure the experience in using BitKeeper taught Linus a lot as well, and I should have mentioned that. And sure, there are a lot of other smart, qualified people who know what they're doing. But I still maintain that Linus' experience in maintaining the kernel makes him the *most* qualified, experience-wise. I may be wrong, but can you point out another project as big, with as many contributors, and where the person responsible for it all is still as deeply involved in getting the actual code of all those contributors to work together?

Comment: @Pankaj Upadhyay: I'm not bashing anyone, I was simply explaining why I downvoted the answer. You said something about "provided a solution first" which I think means you think git was somehow "first" in some regard. What do you think it was first at? It certainly wasn't the first distributed scm tool by a long shot.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: I understand your point, but do you think Linus is the only person to have managed a large software project? There are many extremely smart engineers who have managed very large repositories of code in the past. I think by singleing out Linus you are doing a disservice to many other highly qualified individuals. Plus, just because Linus is great at one sort of software doesn't necessarily mean he is extremely qualified in other areas. There are people that spend their whole careers writing distributed SCM software, but for Linus this was just sort-of a side project.

Comment: "And of course it helped that most of that coding he was dealing was in C" How, exactly? Perhaps you should objectively demonstrate this in some way.

Comment: @DeadMG: The more important part of that statement comes afterwards "...and much of it performance critical". I doubt you'll find many who'll argue that C is not very well suited to implementing low-overhead high-performance code if you know it well.

Answer (score 6):

It was designed pretty much exactly as described in [The Git Parable](http://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html).

> Imagine that you have a computer that has nothing on it but a text editor and a few file system commands. Now imagine that you have decided to write a large software program on this system. Because you’re a responsible software developer, you decide that you need to invent some sort of method for keeping track of versions of your software so that you can retrieve code that you previously changed or deleted. What follows is a story about how you might design one such version control system (VCS) and the reasoning behind those design choices.